# My install is corrupted and I want to back everything up and restore my settings after reinstalling Ubuntu. Is this a good idea?

Tags: 16.04

Long story short: I did a lot of stupid things I shouldn't have done, like repartition the linux-swap partition, erase it, and then repartition it again, deleting my original fstab file, and lord knows what else. Since my install is fully borked, and I'm stuck in emergency mode with no options left except to reinstall the OS, I'd like to now backup and restore the few meagre programs and settings I had.

I still have full access to the drive and all my files, I just can't boot into Ubuntu. I'm not interested in solving that issue since I don't have the time to sit down and try a million different things.

What I do want to know is this: is it a wise idea to create a partition image of the borked Ubuntu install using Disk Utility from a Live USB? I just want my startup application commands, certain programs like Firefox and Thunderbird, which I spent a lot of time setting up, and other small changes I made to /etc/modprobe.d, among other things.

If I restore the partition image to my drive after reinstalling Ubuntu, will my installation get corrupted again (since the original install's fstab is corrupted)?

How can I go about salvaging my files and programs. What I really want to preserve and restore are my programs and their data, like Firefox, Fingerprint GUI, Thunderbird, Redshift, Xinput settings, my startup application commands, etc.

Right now I'm back up /home and /usr only.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have settings in /etc, you probably should have backed that up also. Or if just one or two changes may not be too difficult to reset. All you data & almost all desktop settings are in /home. I also suggest backing up list of installed apps, but if you cannot boot difficult to get a list. See this on backups: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2368992 and I still basically do this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1748541 More detail on  files to backup - post #3:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1500559
& http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1883834

Comment: The simple answer, back-up only your user files to an **external** hard drive or USB stick. You also indicated that you want to save Firefox and Thunderbird configurations. That can be done. Visit their respective websites.  That also goes for saving other program configuration files. After verifying a successful back-up, do a fresh install of Ubuntu on your internal hard drive.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've chosen to make a partition image that I can mount and copy folders from. It's night where I live so I can let it work on backing up to my 4TB HDD for an hour while I sleep.  Question: if I restore the partition using disk utility in the new Ubuntu install, will I end up with a corrupted OS since my fstab file is messed up?

Comment: I don't know what would happen with your fstab, you'll just have to try it and see! Let us know how it goes, if you can.